# Android SDK how to OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, sdk

guys I need help with this code :

```
    public  View.OnClickListener btnGetLastLocationOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                getMyLocation();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this,
                        "!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this,
                    "mGoogleApiClient == null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
```

so what I want to do is when I click on btnGetLocation this code should work, but instead the code works automatically when I start the activity so how can I make works only when I click on the button ?

I hope you guys understand the problem, I'm new Android developer so I'm still learning forgive me for my stupid question.

thank you

*** Update :

here is the whole code :

```
 TextView txtmylink;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Button getlastlocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtmylink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mylink);
    getlastlocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getlastlocation);
    getlastlocation.setOnClickListener(getlastlocationOnClickListener);

    // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}

View.OnClickListener getlastlocationOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                getMyLocation();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "mGoogleApiClient == null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

private void getMyLocation() {
    try {
        /* code should explicitly check to see if permission is available
        (with 'checkPermission') or explicitly handle a potential 'SecurityException'
         */
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            txtmylink.setText(String.valueOf("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=") +
                    String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()) +
                    String.valueOf(",")+ String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "mLastLocation == null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "SecurityException:\n" + e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    getMyLocation();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "onConnectionSuspended: " + String.valueOf(i),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            "onConnectionFailed: \n" + connectionResult.toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your full class code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
          if (view.getId() == R.id.btnGetLocation)
             if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                 if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                     getMyLocation();
                 } else {
                     Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this,
                         "!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
              } else {
                  Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this,
                      "mGoogleApiClient == null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
         }
```

If still not works write your code like this :

your activity must implement OnClickListener and

```
btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(this)
```

and you will have the onClick like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
              if (view.getId() == R.id.btnGetLocation)
                 if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
                     if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                         getMyLocation();
                     } else {
                         Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this,
                             "!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this,
                          "mGoogleApiClient == null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
             }
```

Comment: thanks man but still I'm having the same issue which is the value get loaded once I start the activity, if you please can help I'll be thankful for it.

Comment: have you use this hints : btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(this)... ?

Comment: yes but I got red line under(this), just to be clear this code
    btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(this)
 should be  in this void
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState

Comment: you go redlines because you doesn't implement on the `OnClickListener` interface in your activity.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you haven't associated the `View.onClickListener` object you've written to anything yet. Thus when the activity is started the listener's code gets executed. When you want a specific view say 'A' to respond to a click, you associate a `View.onClickListener` to it. So in your case add the following.

```
yourbutton.setOnClickListener(btnGetLastLocationOnClickListener)
```

Make sure you've bound the `yourbutton` to the `Button` view.

Comment: worked 100% thanks man, now the button is working, but still when I start the activity automatically get the value and put it in the textbox and also when I click the button it do the same thing, so I want only the button to get the value,I'll be more than happy if you could help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it using the following code

```
btnGetLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetLocation); // or whatever you called the button
btnGetLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
             if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                 getMyLocation();
             } else {
                 Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this,
                     "!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
          } else {
              Toast.makeText(AddEditActivity.this,
                  "mGoogleApiClient == null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
     }
}
```

Note that you can add this code in the `onCreate()` method to make it work

Comment: the answer of @not_again_stackoverflow is worked for me but still when I start the activity automatically get the value and put it in the textbox and also when I click the button it do the same thing, so I want only the button to get the value,I'll be more than happy if you could help please

Comment: I've updated the main question would please check it out?